# How to enable SFTP but disable shell for root

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, root, sshd

I already have SFTP for root user enabled on my server but I do not want any user to use root to execute any statements on the terminal. They should use their accounts. I have tried setting `PermitRootLogin no` in the sshd_config but I could not upload files to the server using SFTP. I also tried changing the shell to nologin and false but I cannot upload files.

So my issue is how can I be able to securely FTP files using root but not be able to use root on the terminal via ssh?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The important part is, that whatever configuration files you change to disallow a root shell, a root SFTP can just overwrite it with a file of his or her chosing or alterntively replace the `sftp` executable with whatever he or she wants. Even adding a simple `cron` file to start a reverse shell will do the trick.

In short: root SFTP implies root shell.

I recommend you rethink the need for a root SFTP - most likely some work on file/directory permissions will do the trick much more securely (or a `bindfs` mount if must be)